# HTML select onchange accessibility concerns

Tags: javascript, html, accessibility, onchange

We have a request to use a `select` element's `onchange` to trigger a move to a new page.

In the past, web accessibility literature I've read has generally advised against doing this.  This was on the grounds that it breaks user expectation, and browsers (particularly IE < 6) fired the change event even when moving through options with the keyboard, making it impossible for keyboard-only users to make a selection.

IE6+ and all other more modern browsers I have tested fire the `select` `onchange` when an option is actually selected by mouse or enter key.  Analytics for the application in question show that earlier IE browsers are essentially eradicated (< 0.01%)

Given that our users will be able to operate these `select` elements properly with a keyboard only, should this feature still be considered an impediment to accessibility?  This behavior seems so common nowadays that I wonder also if it really still does break user expectation in a meaningful way?

**EDIT:** IE behaves differently if the `select` is focused with the mouse or keyboard.  When focused with the mouse, keyboarding through options does not fire `onchange` but when tabbing to focus it via keyboard, the `onchange` does fire when arrowing through.

Comment: Wait a second, did you just imply that IE6 is a modern browser? ;)

Comment: What exactly are your question about?

Comment: @Andrew Marshall After typing that sentence I hoped no one would think that.

Comment: @Fernando Should the practice of using a `select` to trigger a move to a new page *still* be avoided because of accessibility concerns?  Is that clearer?

Comment: Now it is. I think sometimes it is very useful, depends exactly what  your needs since it is provided with the most browsers in the market. I use myself it since I had started to programming ... why "be avoided"? give us one good reason to...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using the `onchange` event of the `select` element to navigate between pages can definitely [pose an accessibility problem for keyboard-only users](http://www.themaninblue.com/writing/perspective/2004/10/19/).

There is at least [one method of creating accessible `select` elements with `onchange` handlers](http://www.themaninblue.com/experiment/AccessibleSelect/) and it has been on the interwebs since 2004!

Direct link to the [Accessible Select](http://www.themaninblue.com/experiment/AccessibleSelect/scripts/select_onchange.js) code.

Comment: I've read the iCITA document before and it would seem it's out of date.  It says "On most browser the use of the up and down arrow keys triggers the onChange"   However, all browsers I have tested do not fire the `onchange` with each keyboard change.  Instead it's fired when the enter key is pressed or the control loses focus.

Comment: Oh, wait a minute - in IE it seems that the onchange doesn't fire if you first focus the select with the mouse and keyboard through it.  However, if you focus the select with the keyboard, the onchange does indeed fire on every subsequent keyboard motion.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with you that this type of functionality is very common.  However, most sites use links instead of a `<select>` to achieve the effect (if I'm not mistaken).  I.E. it's the standard (pun intended).

[image]